# Jenkins Powershell Output

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I would like to capture the output of some variables to be used elsewhere in the job using [Jenkins Powershell plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/PowerShell+Plugin).

Is this possible?

My goal is to build the latest tag somehow and the powershell script was meant to achieve that, outputing to a text file would not help and environment variables can't be used because the process is seemingly forked unfortunately

Comment: To be used elsewhere in the job

Comment: well, set environment variable? $env:TestVariable = "This is a test environment variable."

Comment: unfortunately, the process is seeminly forked and environment variables won't work :(

Comment: Well, I don't think there is a clear way to do that. Output to text file?

Comment: @4c74356b41 My goal is to build the latest tag somehow and the powershell script was meant to achieve that, outputing to a text file  would not help unfortunately

Comment: It can help if combined with EnvInject plugin. You can create a text file with key value pairs from powershell then export them into the build using the EnvInject plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Besides EnvInject the another common approach for sharing data between build steps is to store results in files located at job workspace.

The idea is to skip using environment variables altogether and just write/read files.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only solution is to combine with EnvInject plugin. You can create a text file with key value pairs from powershell then export them into the build using the EnvInject plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You should make the workspace persistant for this job , then you can save the data you need to file. Other jobs can then access this persistant workspace or use it as their own as long as they are on the same node.

Another option would be to use jenkins built in artifact retention, at the end of the jobs configure page there will be an option to retain files specified by a match (e.g *.xml or last_build_number). These are then given a specific address that can be used by other jobs regardless of which node they are on , the address can be on the master or the node IIRC.

Answer (score 0):

For the simple case of wanting to read a single object from Powershell you can convert it to a JSON string in Powershell and then convert it back in Groovy. Here's an example:

```
def pathsJSON = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: "ConvertTo-Json ((Get-ChildItem -Path *.txt) | select -Property Name)");
def paths = [];
if(pathsJSON != '') {
    paths = readJSON text: pathsJSON
}
```