# How to send value from powershell script to the jenkinsfile

Tags: powershell, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have to send buildId value from powershell script to the jenkinsfile pipeline. I am trying something like below. Is this right approach?

**powershell script**

```
if($out -match "buildId-") {               
           
            $splitline = $out.Split("-")    
           echo "splitline: " $splitline                
            $buildId= $splitline[1]
            echo "buildId: " $buildId
            $buildIds= $env:$buildId.Value              
        }
```

then want to use that build to pass as a parameter to trigger the build job.

**Jenkinsfile**

```
build job: 'build_Test', parameters: [validatingString(name: 'buildId', value: '$buildIds'), string(name: 'TASK', value: 'build')]
```

Comment: How are you executing the script? Can you share the section of the Pipeline that executes the Script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give it a shot, but I'm not sure simply adding it to an environment variable will allow you to access the value from the Jenkinsfile. You can find more about this problem in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900678/jenkins-powershell-output). However, you maybe able to achieve your goal via the [EnvInject plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/envinject/), or simply store the value in a file in your workspace and access it via Jenkins later.